# How can I hide part of a Sprite2D which is out of TileMap's tiles? Godot 4 beta 16

Tags: godot, godot-shader-language

I am making a blood traces, but sometimes traces can spawn in the way like this, so I have a part of my trace which is out of wall.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRKy4.png)
So how can I cut out or hide this part?

I tried to do that with [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9toPe.png) this option, but PointLight2D not showing my trace at all.

Comment: Well I understood what my method should work, but there is bug - https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/49909
So I am searching for other methods

Comment: Just to clarify, the blood is a Sprite, and the wall is a TileMap. You want the blood to be visible only if it overlaps the wall?

Comment: Yeah, absolute.

Comment: So the part of Sprite which is NOT overlap the wall, somehow need to be cuted out or something